# Having 2 foreign keys from one table in the same table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-migrations

I am trying to implement comment replying feature to my project, however i am not very sure with the method i m using. My basic idea is to keep all the comments in one table, while having another table **comments_replies** which will have the parent comment(comment) and the comment(reply). now i have something like this is migrations of **comments_replies**:

```
create_table :comments_replies do |t|
  t.integer :parent_comment_id, index: true, foreign_key_column_for: :comments, null: false
  t.integer :reply_comment_id, index: true, foreign_key_column_for: :comments, null: false
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

and in model comments_reply.rb

```
belongs_to :comment, class_name: 'Comment'
```

and in model comment.rb

```
has_many :comments_replies, foreign_key: :parent_comment_id, foreign_key: :reply_comment_id
```

as for the second part since i m trying to use RSPEC for testing purposes, in model comments_reply_spec.rb i have:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CommentsReply, type: :model do
  let(:comments_reply) { create(:comments_reply) }
  subject { comments_reply }

  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:parent_comment_id) }
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:reply_comment_id) }
end
```

but i am not sure how to test this case properly, so any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve could be done from "Comment" model itself. You just need another column 'parent_id' in "Comment" which will reference to parent Comment in same table. For all those main "Comments"(which are not replied to any comment) column 'parent_id' will be null.

So your model will look like below

```
class Comment 
  belongs_to :parent_comment, foreign_key: :parent_comment_id, class_name: 'Comment'
  has_many :replies, foreign_key: :parent_comment_id, class_name: 'Comment'
end
```

**With your current approach**

You have specify association with two foreign_key which is wrong. In your "Comment" model you need to association.
1) for all replies of a comment 2) For getting parent comment.

```
has_many :comments_replies, foreign_key: :parent_comment_id
has_many :replies, through: :comment_replies

has_one :parent_comment_reply, foreign_key: :reply_comment_id, class_name: 'CommentReply'
has_one :parent_comment, through: :parent_comment_reply
```

Also in your CommentReply model

```
belongs_to :parent_comment, foreign_key: :parent_comment_id, class_name: 'Comment'
belongs_to :reply_comment, foreign_key: :reply_comment_id, class_name: 'Comment'
```

Your specs looks like below

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CommentsReply, type: :model do
  let(:parent_comment){ create(:comment) }
  let(:child_comment) { create(:comment) }

  let(:comment_reply) { create(:comment_reply, parent_comment_id: parent_comment.id, reply_comment_id: child_comment.id) }

  subject { comment_reply }

  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:parent_comment_id) }
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:reply_comment_id) }

  it "should correctly identify the parent/child relationship" do
    expect(comment_reply.reply_comment.id).to be_eql(child_comment.id)
    expect(comment_reply.parent_comment.id).to be_eql(parent_comment.id)
  end

end
```

Comment: I missed the suggested approach, i believe it will be easier and much more useful, however how should i specify that parent_id field in migration and model, is it okay to simply write in migration:
     t.integer :parent_id, index: true, foreign_key_column_for: :comments, null: false
and in Comment model:
    belongs_to :comment, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: 'Comment'
one more thing, in the Comment model, do i need to write something like:
    has_many :comments, foreign_key: :parent_id